# same active record dataset across many instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have a model say modela with a calculate field. like below

```
class modelA < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessor : calc_field

def calc_field
   @stuff =  modelb.all
   //do fancy things with stuff
end

end
```

now my problem is if i have 100 records of modelA. the modelb.all gets called a 100times. but its the same dataset each time. but the query gets sent out a 100 times.

is there anyway/anywhere i can declare @stuff globally so its gets shared across all instances of modelA. so it gets called only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways on how to tackle this problem.

Solution A:

```
class modelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor : calc_field

  def calc_field(modelb_info)
     @stuff =  modelb_info
     //do fancy things with stuff
  end

end
```

And then in your code work flow

```
model_info = ModelB.all
model_a_array.collect{|model_a| model_a model_info}
```

Solution B

```
class modelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  @@stuff ||= ModelB.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class variable.

```
def calc_field
   @@stuff ||=  modelb.all
   //do fancy things with stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the way of getting the ModelA instances, I would suggest this:

```
modelas = ModelA.includes(:modelbs)
```

From then on, the database will not be hit anymore when you call (e.g.)

```
modelas.first.calc_field
```

I hope that helps